# Relating The Concept of All Possible Outcomes With Number of Angles (& Sides) Within a Polygon

Tags: python, python-3.x, probability, angle

I am trying to find all possible angles and sides in a given shape. However, I am struggling. This is the start of my code.

```
SidesNumber = int(input("How many sides does your shape have: "))
SidesNumber = str(SidesNumber)
ShapeName = input("What is your shape's name. Please enter "+ SidesNumber +" letters: ")
SidesNumber = int(SidesNumber)
while (len(ShapeName) != SidesNumber) or(not ShapeName.isalpha()):
    if (len(ShapeName) != SidesNumber) and(not ShapeName.isalpha()):
        print("Your input does not match the number of vertices your shape has and does not consist of only letters!") 
        SidesNumber = str(SidesNumber)
        ShapeName = input("What is your shape's name. Please enter "+ SidesNumber +" letters: ")
        SidesNumber = int(SidesNumber)
    elif len(ShapeName) != SidesNumber:
        print("Your input does not match the number of vertices your shape has!")
        SidesNumber = str(SidesNumber)
        ShapeName = input("What is your shape's name. Please enter "+ SidesNumber +" letters: ")
        SidesNumber = int(SidesNumber)
    elif not ShapeName.isalpha():
        print("Your input does not consist of letters only!")
        SidesNumber = str(SidesNumber)
        ShapeName = input("What is your shape's name. Please enter "+ SidesNumber +" letters: ")
        SidesNumber = int(SidesNumber)
```

Now what I want to do is to get the computer to calculate all the different angles and sides based on the users' inputs.
So if they enter SidesNumber and ABC for the ShapeName I want the computer to find all the angles and sides or all the possible outcomes in other words. So the angles should be ∠ABC, ∠ACB, ∠BAC. And the sides should be AB, BC, AC.

Furthermore, I want these results to be saved in different variables, something like `side1 = 'AB'`and `side2 ='BC'` and `side3 = 'AC'`. For angles something like `angle1 = '∠ABC'` and `angle1 = '∠ACB'` and `angle1 = '∠BAC'`

I already of this code:

```
import itertools
dataset = ['1','2','3A','4']
var = list(itertools.combinations(dataset, 3))
print(var)
```

But it seems to be useless for me.

Comment: By the way, does any one know how to get this symbol '∠' into python without having to copy it and paste it.

Comment: You may be able to enter it via the keyboard depending on your OS and text editor. It may also be possible using some type of macro. On Windows you could use [`autohotkey`](https://autohotkey.com/).

Comment: Why does `itertools.combinations()` seem useless?

Comment: It does not allow me to save the results as independent variables and it cannot randomise letters without any numbers next to them. Thanks for your interest though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely follow your description of what you're trying to do, but think these examples of generating the outcomes might be helpful:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = [iter(iterable) for _ in range(2)]
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

# hardcode a name for non-interactive testing
shape_name = 'ABC'

sides = [''.join(pair) for pair in pairwise(shape_name + shape_name[0])]
print('sides: {}'.format(sides))

def angle_name(shape_name, side):
    this = shape_name.index(side[-1])  # index of letter for end of this segment
    try:
        nx = shape_name[this+1]  # get letter for next segment
    except IndexError:
        nx = shape_name[0]  # wrap around

    return '∠'+side+nx

angles = [angle_name(shape_name, side) for side in sides]
print('angles: {}'.format(angles))
```

Output:

```
sides: ['AB', 'BC', 'CA']
angles: ['∠ABC', '∠BCA', '∠CAB']
```

Regardless, I also strongly suggest you read and start following to [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), particularly the [**Naming Conventions**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) section.

Comment: ObGamEr OGE: Glad to hear it may help you. BTW, you might want to add a check to make sure the `shape_name` is composed of a set of unique letters because the `shape_name.index()` won't work as expected otherwise. This can be verified by insuring that `len(shape_name) == len(set(shape_name))`.

Comment: this is what I used as a checker 
`while len(shape_name) != len(set(shape_name)):`  
is that fine